# Selecting data between 2 date values using SQL and VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm writing the following SQL statement in-order to get a sum value from a specific table using VB.NET. But, I keep getting the following error

itCode is a variable

```
Dim strSql As String = "SELECT sum(purchase_qty) FROM TB_STOCK WHERE it_code='" & itCode & "' AND added_date BETWEEN #07/21/2020 00:00:00# AND #07/21/2020 23:59:59#"
```

> error : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '00'.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that SQL Server doesn't understand date literals like that. That would work for Access but different databases require different syntax. You should use text literals in yyyy-MM-dd format:

```vb
"' AND added_date BETWEEN '2020-07-21 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-21 23:59:59'"
```

That said, I'm guessing that you're going to have to vary those dates at some point, so you probably ought to be using parameters. You definitely should be using a parameter for the `it_code` value, e.g.

```vb
Dim sql = "SELECT sum(purchase_qty) FROM TB_STOCK WHERE it_code = @it_code AND added_date BETWEEN @added_date_start AND @added_date_end"
Dim command As New SqlCommand(sql, connection)

With command.Parameters
    .Add("@it_code", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = itCode
    .Add("@added_date_start", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = myDate
    .Add("@added_date_end", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = myDate.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1)
End With
```

I agree with Rodney Ellis about not using `BETEWEEN` too. I would do it like this:

```vb
Dim sql = "SELECT sum(purchase_qty) FROM TB_STOCK WHERE it_code = @it_code AND added_date >= @added_date_start AND added_date < @added_date_end"
Dim command As New SqlCommand(sql, connection)

With command.Parameters
    .Add("@it_code", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = itCode
    .Add("@added_date_start", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = myDate
    .Add("@added_date_end", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = myDate.AddDays(1)
End With
```

The last two examples both assume that `myDate` already has the time zeroed. If it doesn't, you can use `myDate.Date`.

Comment: I was using this statement inside of a function. I passed the date values as parameters. But, I can see that, this is the better method and I'm going to use it. thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim strSql As String = "SELECT sum(purchase_qty) FROM TB_STOCK 
WHERE it_code='" & itCode & "' AND added_date BETWEEN '2020-07-20 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-21 23:59:59'"
```

Also, don't use BETWEEN -
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9316/sql-server-between-dates-issue/